# Parse JSON string - ios sdk

Tags: json, ios

```
{"aps":{
        "alert":"New Test For The Win",
        "sound":"default"
        },
  "fk_device":"1513"
}
```

I have this JSON NSString. How can I parse this JSON string and get fk_device value?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this library [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit). To get the string, you can do something like this:

```
NSDictionary *deserializedData = [jsonString objectFromJSONString];
NSString *string = [deserializedData objectForKey:@"fk_device"];
```